# In openerp . Can i show data of two tables data in one single xml file

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm having a custom module.I have created two .py files and my doubt is can i show both table data in one xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. 
Example is here: https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/ro/developer/5_16_data_serialization/xml_serialization/ or just look on existing modules.